# Mongo Db Connection Error: Certificate hase expired

Tags: python, mongodb

I have been trying to connect to mongoDB atlas using python. But even after all the correct credentials I am encountering this error
Here is my code:

```
uri = "mongodb+srv://ritvikravikumar:password@cluster.vnfabix.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster"

# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(uri)

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I have tried repeatedly checking the credentials and making sure the server is up and running but still this error occurs.

Comment: The full error message would be helpful